# Manually Adding h265 codec support to FFMPEG v1.0.10

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution. I am using Debian 7 wheezy, I have managed to get as far as having the following version installed.

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.10 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers

built on Jul 25 2014 07:50:40 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

But as you will see below there is no H265 support which is making for a real headache trying to convert iOS MOV files to MP4. Has anybody had any luck with this ordeal? I've looked through stackoverflow for 3 hours and see nothing even close here.

```
 ffmpeg -codecs | grep h26
 DEV.L. h261                 H.261
 DEV.L. h263                 H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 
 version 2
 D.V.L. h263i                Intel H.263
 DEV.L. h263p                H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_crystalhd h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
```

Using a different software version at this time is not an option, I am aware of how lacking the packages can be with Debian.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not possible.**

The HEVC/H.265 decoder was added on 2013-08, and the demuxer on 2013-10, but the FFmpeg 1.0 release branch is from 2012-09. New features are not backported to releases, only bug fixes, so although 1.0.10 was released on 2014-07 does not include support either.

You will need to use a modern FFmpeg version. A simple option is to [download an already compiled, recent static `ffmpeg` build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).